# working with a timestamp in postgress

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build and populate a table in postgres. The final product should look something like this  [image: my goal]

These are the columns the table should have and the data types I think they should use, (if you have sugesstions as to better fitting data types I'd like to know them).

- id integer
- name VARCHAR(60)
- gender  VARCHAR(1)
- age integer
- intake_date timestamp
- adoption_date timestamp

I created the table with this command,

```
pets=# CREATE TABLE cats (
id integer,name text,gender text, age integer, intake_date timestamp, 
adoption_date timestamp);
```

then tried to add all my lines in this single command and got

```
pets=# INSERT INTO cats (id,name,gender,age, intake_date,adoption_date)
VALUES
(00001, 'Mushi', 'M', 1,2016-01-09, 2016-03-22)
(00002, 'Seashell' , 'F', 7,2016-01-09)
(00003,'Azul', 'M', 3, 2016-01-11, 2016-04-17)
(00004, 'Victoire' ,'M', 7, 2016-01-11, 2016-09-01)
(00005, 'Nala', 'F', 12016-01-12);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 4: (00002, 'Seashell' , 'F', 7,2016-01-09)
```

I then partially realized that postgres would have a problem because some of the `adoption_date` columns where left blank. so I tried to at least add one row with

```
pets=# INSERT INTO cats (id,name,gender,age, intake_date,adoption_date)
VALUES
(00001,'Mushi','M', 1, 2016-01-09, 2016-03-22);
```

and got back an error of

```
ERROR:  column "intake_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but 
expression is of type integer
LINE 3: (00001,'Mushi','M', 1, 2016-01-09, 2016-03-22);
                           ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

So my three problems or unknowns are

1. How do I create a table with a column that has a datatype of timestamp that is left blank at entry?
2. How should I be entering timestamps?
3. Are there better datatypes I should be using

Comment: put quotes around timestamps, i.e. `'2016-01-09'`, integers don't need to be entered with 0's padded, i.e. `1` instead of `0001`. unless the `not null` or `primary key` constraint is specified on the column, it will accept nulls. data types are fine.

Comment: The ID column could be a `serial` so the it will automatically generate itself as you enter rows, and as sated above don't pad integers with leading zeros that is just a waste of effort.

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp data should pass within single quotes

```
INSERT INTO cats (id,name,gender,age, intake_date,adoption_date)
VALUES(00001, 'Mushi', 'M', 1,'2016-01-09', '2016-03-22');
```

Just use `NULL` when you want to insert blank value

```
INSERT INTO cats (id,name,gender,age, intake_date,adoption_date)
VALUES(00002, 'Seashell' , 'F', 7,'2016-01-09',null);
```

or

Create Table like below(*assign `default Null` to a column that you want to leave blank when inserting*)

```
CREATE TABLE cats1 (
id integer
,name text
,gender text
,age integer
,intake_date timestamp
,adoption_date timestamp default Null
);
```